# Can you use parameter/variables/placeholders for values for future use in a Specflow scenario?

Tags: specflow

In previous job I have used DBFit and used parameters (variables/placeholders) for values

example:

```
|Key? |
|>>Key|

!|Query|SELECT Status FROM Confirm WHERE Name='xyz' |
| Status    | Key   |
| Confirmed | <<Key |
```

I am now using SpecFlow and wondered if it has similar functionality

example: ( I have used << and >> here just for explanation )

Given I get Initial for 
And the 1st response should contain

```
   | Name  | string | "xyz"     |
   | Key   | string | >>{Key}   |
```

When I get Confirm for

Then the 1st response should contain

```
   | Name  | string | "xyz"     |
   | Key   | string | <<{Key}   |
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Scenario Outlines.

With them, you can specify a table with your parameters. So in your case, it is looking something like this:

```
Scenario Outline: Title for your Scenario Outline

Given I get Initial for And the 1st response should contain 
| field | type   | assertion | 
| Name  | string | "xyz"     |
| Key   | string | <Key>     |

When I get Confirm for

Then the 1st response should contain 
| field | type   | assertion | 
| Name  | string | "xyz"     | 
| Key   | string | <Key>     |

Examples:
    | Key      |
    | example1 |
    | example2 |
    | example3 |
```

Be aware that you have here two different types of tables. The table at your steps is an argument for the step.
The Examples table at the end are the concrete examples. So the Scenario is executed once per each entry in this table.

You can use the parameters from the example table with a simple <COLUMN_NAME> placeholder.

Docs: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Gherkin/Gherkin-Reference.html#scenario-outline

Comment: Thank you but this is not exactly what I am after.  Basically I don't know what the <key> is, but I do know the name.  So, I have an 'Initial' call using the name to get the <key> (GIVEN)  I then want to use the <key> in a subsequent call (WHEN)